# If a character gets Lucky and dies, can I still play the bonus game?

Tags: super-mario-rpg-2023

According to the [Super Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Bonus_Flower), the Bonus Flower has a LUCKY! effect where, if a character gets it during battle, the player can play a "[Wheeere's Yoshi?!](https://www.mariowiki.com/Wheeere%27s_Yoshi%3F!)" bonus game after the fight to double their coins or experience.

Let's say Mallow gets the Lucky bonus flower, but then he dies in battle and I swap him out for Peach. Do I still get to play the bonus game when the fight ends?

[image: Mario getting the LUCKY! effect]

Comment: I think it's tied to the whole party, not the single character. No way to prove this.